# Wrong last name on my credit card

Tags: credit-card, credit

I just ordered a Credit card and it has my former last name on it instead of my new last name. Can I still use it or do I have to get a new one?

Comment: Best to check with the issuer.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the online portal to make sure that your profile *there* reflects the name you want on the card right before you call them, just to make sure it goes efficiently: that way, you can easily tell them that "the card you sent me doesn't match the name on my account" so it doesn't make a less-skilled rep think that you're calling in to *change* your name, just that you're trying to get the _card_ corrected

Comment: (I was sent a card by Discover which didn't match the name on my account, and they trivially resolved it when I called them to ask about it.)

Answer (score 6):

Odds are very good you can just go ahead and use the card: almost never does anyone bother to look at your card, even in the rare case when they handle it.

Not a bad idea to call the issuer to get a card with your correct legal name on it, however.

Comment: I agree with this. My wife still has about half of her stuff with her maiden name, and the other half with my last name. Nobody ever cares, except for airport security, and sometimes me when I do store/food pickup for her orders and I never know which last name to give them.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be fine 99% of the time, but it could occasionally cause issues. Some places ID for credit cards to prevent fraud, even though it's technically against their agreement with MasterCard etc. to do so. So you might occasionally be refused if the name on your card doesn't match your ID. There might also be occasions where your credit card could be used as a form of ID (e.g. when you forward your mail to a new address) but you can't use it because the name is wrong on it.

So long as you have a backup card, it's not going to cause you major problems, but I'd get a new one with the correct name anyway.